# How to save correctly in localstorage?

Tags: angular

How do I save an active checkbox to local storage? At the moment, all active checkbox disappear after page refresh.

What am I doing wrong?

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('selectedNode')) {
    this.load();
  } else {
    localStorage.getItem('selectedNode');
    this.load();
  }
}

markSelectedNodes() {
  for (const node of this.treeData) {
    if (this.descendantsPartiallySelected(node)) {
      node.selected = true;
      this.checkDescendants(node);
      localStorage.setItem('selectedNode', node);
    } else {
      node.selected = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the local storage getting emptied when you reload the page? Did you check that?

Answer (score 0):

normally we use localstorage to save data to the user side, def :

> LocalStorage is a type of web storage that allows JavaScript sites and apps to store and access data right in the browser with no expiration date. This means the data stored in the browser will persist even after the browser window has been closed.
>
> more info at https://blog.logrocket.com/the-complete-guide-to-using-localstorage-in-javascript-apps-ba44edb53a36/

but in your case, this data should be stored in a database